# Can i restrict user login based on cipher suite?

Tags: login, transaction-security-policy

When we download the login history, we get the Ciphersuite and TLS protocol used by users during login. While I can write a Transaction Security policy to block users based on TLS protocol, I don't find a way to restrict user's access when a particular CipherSuite is used. Is there a way to achieve that?

I thought of writing a trigger on LoginEvent but looks like it isn't supported. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [login flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow.htm&type=5)? I don't have time to test it now, but these kinds of flows can do almost anything. It might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I checked that the "TLS Cipher Suite" is not available in the "Builder" of transaction security policy. You can use the "Apex" option with below code.

```
global class RestrictTLSPolicyEventCondition implements TxnSecurity.EventCondition {
public boolean evaluate(SObject event) {
    try {
        String valueName;
        String valueFlag;
        LoginEvent le = (LoginEvent) event;
        Map < String, MyMetadataType__mdt > mapCipher = MyMetadataType__mdt.getAll();
        for (String nameCipher: mapCipher.keySet()) {
            valueName = mapCipher.get(nameCipher).MasterLabel;
            valueFlag = mapCipher.get(nameCipher).Flag__c;
            if ((le.CipherSuite == valueName) && (valueFlag == 'true')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Exception ----->' + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}}
```

- You can add the cipher values you want to restrict in the custom metadata type(Here: MyMetadataType__mdt) add set Flag__c to true/false
- It is also worth noting that during the handshake, the client offers its suites and Salesforce selects the most secure

[Ref Doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000351980&type=1)

> Salesforce provides a suite of protocols and ciphers which focus on security while allowing for a reasonable degree of compatibility. Our servers will negotiate to the most secure combination the client can support.
> Clients able to support TLS v1.2 will connect with that protocol.
> Ciphers are treated in the same way. The most secure cipher that can be negotiated with the client is used.

- If Salesforce selects one that you wouldn’t approve, but you are allowing one with a lower priority, that will never be used.
  Another thing to consider is that the connection during login and the connection to the “salesforce core ==lightning” are different ones. You should enforce it in both of them.

Comment: I have notified our salesforce product development team that the "TLS Cipher Suite" field should be made available via the Condition Builder too.