# How do I block a specific 'Remote Access 2.0' Application that does not appear to have an associated Connected App for a specific User?

Tags: connected-apps, remote-access, ip

I'm looking for the best practice to block a specific "Remote Access 2.0" application within Salesforce.

For whatever reason, when I go to the connected apps, the Application isn't listed. So I was wondering what my options were.

Obviously, I don't want to prevent the user's regular SAML Sfdc Intiatated SSO logins. Is there a way to specific block this application?

[image]

Comment: If access is via a connected app, you can [block it](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_current_sessions.htm&type=5)

Comment: @identigral unfortunately when I go to connected apps, the application is not listed so I don't believe that is an option

Comment: Did you look under `Manage Apps > Connected Apps OAuth Usage`

Comment: I believe you can use [Transaction Security policy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370190/can-i-restrict-user-login-based-on-cipher-suite) in this case.